# Convert UTC Date to Local Timezone JSP

Tags: jsp, date

I have variable that store data datetime UTC from database. I want to make it in Local datetime format, can i do that?

for example:

> Date dateFromDB = getfromDB();
>
> dateFromDB = UTCtoLocalTimezone(dateFromDB);

What the code in method UTCtoLocalTimezone?

Or do you have any better solution?
thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net):

```
DateTimeZone zone = ...;
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date.getTime(), zone);
```

Joda Time is a much better date and time API than the built-in one, but that would work too:

```
TimeZone zone = ...;
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(zone);
calendar.setTime(date);
```

I *wouldn't* use the (deprecated) `Date` constructor though. For one thing, it doesn't do what you appear to think it does... this:

```
 new Date(2012,03,02,11,30,0);
```

constructs a value representing the 2nd of February in the year 3912...

This won't be a problem if you're fetching the `Date` from the database, but obviously it will affect unit testing. You should really avoid all the deprecated members of `Date` - they're deprecated for good reason.

Comment: it's just to pretend example datetime value from database, how to get the client zone?

Comment: @Nore: You'll have to ask the user. Javascript can give you the current offset from UTC, but that's all. Of course you could do the conversion client-side if you wanted.

Comment: In the end, before i got to go the page which need UTC, i use JavaScript to get the int GMT value and pass it with parameter, but thanks :)